# Redirect to page after login, when you came from specific page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need a very simple thing in wordpres
First one is:
I have a specific page called profile - when user can edit his/her info and change password.
If someone is not logged-in - he should be redirected to loginpage.
So, it would be something on this page

```
 if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
 } else {
 wp_redirect( 'http://www.mysite.com/wp-login.php' ); exit; }
```

That's part ok, but if someone login (push the button 'login') i'd like him to go back to the previous site. So I came up with this

```
 wp_redirect( 'http://www.mysite.com/wp-login.php?=profile' ); exit; }
```

And then, php would check if there's ?=profile in the address and with proper function redirect to /profile after login.

Could please someone help me with the second chunck of code? :) Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want custom redirection, you can use like this

```
$returnPath = get_settings('siteurl') . '/login/?redirect_to=' . urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

<a href="<?php echo $returnPath;?>">Login  link</a>
```

Comment: In my WordPress instance it's `/wp-login.php` instead of `/login/`, but the `redirect_to=` parameter works just like that.

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="http://www.home.com/">
I think that redirects me after logging in. So I should change that value? And how would the wordpress now WHEN redirect me to the my /profile page?
I'm sorry I'm not a php specialist :(

Thanks for helping!

Comment: ya you should replace that "home.com" with `$returnPath`. Now if you want profile page on direct login. it will work as you give. Wordpress redirects to the particular page when it gets parameter `redirect_to`...So you can set that if you not get home.com simply redirect to profile page

Comment: Well i don't think I'm doing everything ok :(
    $returnPath = get_settings('siteurl') . '/wp-login.php?redirect_to=' . urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
I'm using this and it keeps to add /wp-login.php at the end. Everytime, not matter from which site I'd enter.

Comment: while you are redirecting to `$returnPath (I am sure you are redirecting your page to $returnPath)`, are you going on `wp-login.php?redirect_to=...` ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to try [theme my login](http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/faq/) plugin.this will allow you to redirect user  after login to the same page that he is in ,before login.

Comment: No need for a plugin, WordPress can to that by default (see answer by Dev)

Answer (score -1):

After Login redirect to specific page based on user role

```
  function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $user ) {
    //is there a user to check?
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        //check for admins
        if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
            // redirect them to the default place
            return $redirect_to;
        } else if(in_array( 'buyer', $user->roles )){
            return home_url().'/unmatched-order/';
        }
                else if(in_array( 'supplier', $user->roles )){
            return home_url().'/products-lists/';
        }
    } else {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Hi! The correct arguments for this filter function are `($redirect_to, $requested_redirect_to, $user)`. Your filter even declares **3** arguments.